# matplotlib is plotting bars when I am asking for a line

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Here is some code to help explain the problem:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(500,7), columns=['A', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4','B5', 'B6'])
dfrx = pd.DataFrame({'ranges': dfx.iloc[0]})
dfrx.set_index(np.arange(len(dfrx)),inplace=True)
dfrx.plot.line()
```

With this program I get, as expeced, a single line, with 7 points. X values from 0 to 6 and y values go from -1 to 1.

My problem is with a similar data set which is hard to show here. Instead of 7 B1, B2 etc., there are 712 B1, B2, B... and in addition another 712 C1, ...

Here is a [gist for the data](https://gist.github.com/pitosalas/1b4d637fe15045b81edbb5157649cc81)

When I run code  just like the above against the data set I get a graph that looks like this:

[image]

In other words, it's not a line graph it looks more like a bar graph.

Interestingly, `dfrx.info()` gives this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 719 entries, 0 to 718
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   ranges  719 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 11.2 KB
```

1. Any ideas?
2. Suggest making my code better?

Comment: It looks like your data keeps coming back to zero, can you provide a sample?

Comment: done - see gist above

Comment: Which fields do you want to plot?

Comment: The data is going back to zero.  If that is your bad flag set zeros to NaN.

Comment: You are all exactly right. It wasn't supposed to be going to zero, but it does, all over the place! Thanks. I am still very interested if you have a suggestion on improving the way I did this!

Comment: Maybe something like `dfrx[(dfrx['ranges'] < 100) & (dfrx['ranges'] > 0)].plot.line()`?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the data actually is going to zero! And yes:

```
dfr[dfr['ranges']==0]
```

shows lots of zeros that I wasn't aware of!